# How to calling model function in cgridview button for visible property in yii

Tags: php, yii

How to solve problem?

```
array(
        'header'=>'Manage',
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        'template'=>'{Manage}',
        //'visible'=>'$data->checkSub($data->sub_id)', //it not work not call function
                'visible'=>Model::test(), //it works

        'buttons'=>array(
                'Manage Exam Result'=>array(
                            'label'=>'<i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>',

                        ),
                ),
        ), 
),
```

Answer (score 0):

`visible` is not evaluated for each row, it must be set to true or false in the end. So to determine if current **column** is visible, you have to call single function from your view that returns true or false.

```
[
    ...
    'visible' => Model::checkIfVisibleColumn(),
    ...
],
```

Comment: hi Justinas your answer is right but i have pass some data in function like 'visible'=>Model::Test($data->id) it is not working

Comment: @HirenBhut Than your function is wrong. What if in one line this function returns true while in another it returns false?

Comment: Why not using `'value' => (Model::someFunction()) ? 'the value' : '' ` ?

Comment: @PrabowoMurti This question has nothing to do with column value!

Comment: @Justinas sorry, but the question said it has something to do with the row's value/id. Different row, different value. So `'the value'` should be replaced with `$data->someFunction($data->id)`, cmiiw

Answer (score 0):

```
array(
  'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
                 'buttons'=>array(
                            'manage' => array('visible' => 'name_function($data->id)'),
                  ),
            ),
```